# p4 sync stuck in kubernetes pod

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, synchronization, perforce

I am using kubernetes pod and inside that pod i am trying to sync a 1 Gb file from depot with the command p4 sync -f and I am using Jenkins job to do this. Some times the file get sync but most of the times it got stuck and Jenkins did not show any error but it start the post build action without completing the previous tasks. Any idea about this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. There might not be enough detail in your question in order for people to help you. Also, are you able to reproduce the issue if you trigger the command directly (without Jenkins)?

Comment: Thanks for replying. No if i am using p4 sync inside the pod this issue is not coming. i think it is a bandwidth issue but i am not sure about it. Can you tell me what all details are you talking about? It would be a big help.